# How to check if a letsencrypt certificate has been revoked

Tags: ssl, openssl, ocsp

I am trying to check if a certificate issued by letsencrypt has been revoked based on this [answer](https://serverfault.com/a/732525/246884):

```
 openssl ocsp -issuer highschoolhelper.org_fullchain.crt  -cert highschoolhelper.org_fullchain.crt  \
      -text -url http://ocsp.int-x3.letsencrypt.org  -header "HOST" "ocsp.int-x3.letsencrypt.org"
```

highschoolhelper.org_fullchain.crt content:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----

-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

But I am getting this output instead:

```
OCSP Request Data:
    Version: 1 (0x0)
    Requestor List:
        Certificate ID:
          Hash Algorithm: sha1
          Issuer Name Hash: 7EE66AE7729AB3FCF8A220646C16A12D6071085D
          Issuer Key Hash: 631192891A849CF47501DE858F83FF62B943199A
          Serial Number: 0486E5A1D0B9C6D97280AC24D47C6B552370
    Request Extensions:
        OCSP Nonce:
            0410193D65F8B1D045055EE5862101F61D02
Responder Error: unauthorized (6)
```

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I corrected my question, it seems I was copying the wrong file name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your input file contains two certificates: the leaf certificate first and the chain certificate second. The chain certificate is the issuer of the leaf certificate so it needs to be used for the `-issuer` argument if the leaf certificate is to be checked (`-cert` argument).

Only, you provide the same file both for issuer and cert. In both cases it will take the first certificate out of the file which means it will take the same certificate for issuer and cert - which is wrong. To fix this split your file into two: put the first certificate into `cert.pem` and the second into `issuer.pem` and then try again:

```
$ openssl ocsp -issuer issuer.pem -cert cert.pem \
    -text -url http://ocsp.int-x3.letsencrypt.org  -header "HOST" "ocsp.int-x3.letsencrypt.org"

...
OCSP Response Data:
    ...
    Responder Id: C = US, O = Let's Encrypt, CN = Let's Encrypt Authority X3
    ...
    Cert Status: good
    This Update: May 24 03:00:00 2020 GMT
    Next Update: May 31 03:00:00 2020 GMT
```

Comment: That is explains why the server was returning an error.

Answer (score 1):

Besides Steffen's answer using OCSP you can also use Certificate Transparency Logs search interfaces, that store all certificates, and their revocation status, from any public CA.

If you search with https://crt.sh/?q=highschoolhelper.org you get 7 certificates:

```
crt.sh ID    Logged At  ⇧   Not Before  Not After   Matching Identities     Issuer Name
2848441767  2020-05-24  2020-05-24  2020-08-22  highschoolhelper.org
                                                www.highschoolhelper.org    C=US, O=Let's Encrypt, CN=Let's Encrypt Authority X3
2850401771  2020-05-24  2020-05-24  2020-08-22  highschoolhelper.org    C=US, O=Let's Encrypt, CN=Let's Encrypt Authority X3
2849897415  2020-05-23  2020-05-23  2020-08-21  highschoolhelper.org    C=US, O=Let's Encrypt, CN=Let's Encrypt Authority X3
2845143222  2020-05-23  2020-05-23  2020-08-21  highschoolhelper.org    C=US, O=Let's Encrypt, CN=Let's Encrypt Authority X3
2844662744  2020-05-23  2020-05-23  2020-08-21  highschoolhelper.org    C=US, O=Let's Encrypt, CN=Let's Encrypt Authority X3
2753256176  2020-05-02  2020-05-02  2020-07-31  highschoolhelper.org
                                                mail.highschoolhelper.org
                                                www.highschoolhelper.org    C=US, ST=TX, L=Houston, O="cPanel, Inc.", CN="cPanel, Inc. Certification Authority"
2753256196  2020-05-02  2020-05-02  2020-07-31  highschoolhelper.org
                                                mail.highschoolhelper.org
                                                www.highschoolhelper.org    C=US, ST=TX, L=Houston, O="cPanel, Inc.", CN="cPanel, Inc. Certification Authority"
```

The first certificate in your dump has:

```
        Issuer: C=US, O=Let's Encrypt, CN=Let's Encrypt Authority X3
        Validity
            Not Before: May 24 02:03:23 2020 GMT
            Not After : Aug 22 02:03:23 2020 GMT
        Subject: CN=highschoolhelper.org
```

so that corresponds to the one above as ID 2850401771

Going to https://crt.sh/?id=2850401771 it is not marked yet at revoked (but will be):

[image: Certificate 2850401771 revocation status]

Unless you click on "Check" near OCSP and then you get:

[image: Certificate 2850401771 revocation status after OCSP check]